# MongoDB top selling products query don't work

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have bill schema in my mongodb database, and I want to get top selling products ranked from highest to lowest this is how a document looks like:
but have err ...............................................................................................................///////////////////////////////////..

```
{
    "stringValue": "\"topProducts\"",
    "valueType": "string",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "topProducts",
    "path": "_id",
    "reason": {},
    "name": "CastError",
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"topProducts\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Bill\""
}
```

db

```
const billSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        user : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
        customer: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Customer',
        },
        products: [
            {
                product: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'Product',
                },
                name: {
                    type: String,
                    default: "",
                },
                quantity: {
                    type: Number,
                    default: 0
                },
                price: {
                    type: Number,
                    default: 0
                },
                discount: {
                    type: Number,
                    default: 0
                }
            }
        ],
        total: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        discount: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        netTotal: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        paid: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        paymentMethod: {
            type: String,
            default: "Cash"
        },
        status: {
            type: String,
            default: "Pending"
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }    
);
```

// router

```
router.get("/topProducts", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const topProducts = await Bill.aggregate([
            { $unwind: "$products" },
            { $group: { _id: "$products.product", total: { $sum: "$products.quantity" } } },
            { $sort: { total: -1 } },
            { $limit: 5 },
            { $lookup: { from: "products", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "product" } },
            { $unwind: "$product" },
            { $project: { _id: 0, product: "$product", total: 1 } },
        ]);
        res.status(200).json(topProducts);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the error? What version of the database are you using?

Comment: err is message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"topProducts\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Bill\""
}

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that originally. I don't think the error originates in the code that you've shared. The error suggests that somewhere you are attempting to create a `Bills` object where the `_id` value is the literal string value of `"topProducts"` which doesn't seem correct. Where else do you reference this `topProducts` stuff?